# How to echo xml in php?

Tags: php, xml

I am new to web development and have the assignment to make a simple weather forecast website.

I can echo simple XML

```
<data source="meteofactory" productioncenter="NC Jakarta">
<forecast domain="local">
<issue>
<timestamp>20221003025230</timestamp>
<year>2022</year>
<month>10</month>
<day>03</day>
<hour>02</hour>
<minute>52</minute>
<second>30</second>
</issue>
```

With this

```
<?php

$data = simplexml_load_file("https://data.bmkg.go.id/DataMKG/MEWS/DigitalForecast/DigitalForecast-DKIJakarta.xml") or die("Gagal mengakses!");
echo "<h2>Forecast</h2>";
echo "Date: " . $data->forecast->issue->day . "-" . $data->forecast->issue->month . "-" .  $data->forecast->issue->year . "<be>";

?>
```

But I am confuse for more complicated data with id, type, datetime etc, like this one

```
   data source="meteofactory" productioncenter="NC Jakarta">
<forecast domain="local">
<area id="501192" latitude="-6.203019" longitude="106.731319" coordinate="106.731319 -6.203019" type="land" region="" level="1" description="Jakarta Barat" domain="DKI Jakarta" tags="">
<name xml:lang="en_US">Jakarta Barat</name>
<name xml:lang="id_ID">Kota Jakarta Barat</name>
<parameter id="hu" description="Humidity" type="hourly">
<timerange type="hourly" h="0" datetime="202210030000">
<value unit="%">85</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="6" datetime="202210030600">
<value unit="%">70</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="12" datetime="202210031200">
<value unit="%">90</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="18" datetime="202210031800">
<value unit="%">95</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="24" datetime="202210040000">
<value unit="%">85</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="30" datetime="202210040600">
<value unit="%">70</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="36" datetime="202210041200">
<value unit="%">90</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="42" datetime="202210041800">
<value unit="%">90</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="48" datetime="202210050000">
<value unit="%">90</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="54" datetime="202210050600">
<value unit="%">85</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="60" datetime="202210051200">
<value unit="%">90</value>
</timerange>
<timerange type="hourly" h="66" datetime="202210051800">
<value unit="%">85</value>
</timerange>
</parameter>
```

This code that I tried to make is failing because I am not sure where to put the data for type="hourly" h="66" datetime="202210051800".

```
<?php

$data = simplexml_load_file("https://data.bmkg.go.id/DataMKG/MEWS/DigitalForecast/DigitalForecast-DKIJakarta.xml") or die("Gagal mengakses!");
echo "<h2>Forecast</h2>";

echo "Tanggal: " . $data->area->parameter->timerange->value . "<br>";  

?>
```

Can anyone help me, I want to echo specific data so I can take only the data I need (which is the latest data for today, or maybe the next 3 days), not echo the whole data like with this code

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('https://data.bmkg.go.id/DataMKG/MEWS/DigitalForecast/DigitalForecast-DKIJakarta.xml');
    echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the examples on php.net? Seems pretty straightforward: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Your sample xml is not well formed. Please edit your question and add a short, simplified version of a well formed sample xml, together with the expected output from that sample.